# Jsp: Using c:if not working

Tags: jstl

I want a table which will print the first 10 items in one td, the next 20 in a second td. But the code below doesn't do that.  Instead it takes item[0] and item[10] and so on, and puts them in a table,  but the other items are placed outside the table.

```
<table><tr>    
<c:forEach var="item" items="${itemList}" varStatus="i">
<c:if test="${i.index % 10 == 0}">
  <td>
</c:if>
<a>${item}</a><br>
<c:if test="${i.index % 10 == 0}">
  </td>
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and second test are both true, the closing `</td>` is placed at the same time as the opening `<td>`.

The second `c:if` should use 9 instead of 0.

```
<c:if test="${i.index % 10 == 9}">
  </td>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use i.index < 10. Right now you are using the module (%) which what it does is dividing by 10 and returning the remainder

Answer (score 0):

`<table>
    <tr>

      <c:forEach var="item" items="${itemList}" varStatus="i">
        <c:if test="${i.index < 10}">
          <td>
              <a>${item}</a><br>
          </td>
        </c:if>
       <td>
           <a>${item}</a><br>
       </td>
 </c:forEach>
 </tr>
</table>`

Comment: I tried this code, but it didn't work. It just printed all the items in a straight line. What i want is a table with columns of 10 rows each. The forEach loop goes down each column and then to the next column.